# Remove the Junk charcters from hive tables or from unix

Tags: sql, regex, hadoop, hive, hiveql

We have the tables in hive like below and we are generating the flat files from hive data while we are generating we found that there was junk characteres with in the data like below we have many characters in many columns can any one help us to remove those junk characters from hive table or from unix file ?

ÿ,ä,í,ã

Here problem the same data need to send the downstream when they are loading in to there DB it shows as double dollar but we design code double dollar as column delimiter.

Comment: What are the legal characters?

Comment: The last sentence of your post is not clear.

Comment: Totally we have the 142 tables but i am not in which table which column is having the junk character.basically i am fetching the data from hive and providing to the downstream with delimiter duble dollar through MQHUB server.when ever the downstream is trying to load the data they observed junk characters are converting automaticallly as double dollar here our delimiter is also double dollar. for example in atable i have 11 columns with delimiter double dollar but if that record is having junk character then it shows 12 delimiters. so they unable to insert that particular record.

Comment: Got it. The answer I gave should be fine.

Comment: Is there any way to remove with out creating the table because i am fetching the data from hive table i don't have the access to create table in production perspective ?

Comment: Depends on the type of the columns. try `select array(*) from ... limit 1` and see if it works or return an error.

Comment: I confused a bit will you please let us know the complete syntax....

Comment: `select array(*) from {your table} limit 1`

Comment: Are you still there?

Answer (score 0):

Basic concept

```
hive> select regexp_replace('Hÿelloä íworlãd','[^a-zA-Z ]','');
OK
Hello world
```

#### Demo

Removing undesired character from the whole table and exporting it to a file.

```
create table t (i int,s1 string,s2 string);
insert into t values (1,'Hÿelloä','íworlãd'),(2,'ãGããood','Byÿe');

select * from t;

+---+---------+---------+
| i | s1      | s2      |
+---+---------+---------+
| 1 | Hÿelloä | íworlãd |
| 2 | ãGããood | Byÿe    |
+---+---------+---------+
```

---

```
create external table t_ext (rec string) 
row format delimited 
fields terminated by '0' 
location '/user/hive/warehouse/t'
;
```

---

```
insert overwrite local directory '/tmp/t_ext'
select  regexp_replace(regexp_replace(rec,'[^a-zA-Z0-9 \\01]',''),'\\x01','<--->') 
from    t_ext
;
```

---

```
! ls /tmp/t_ext
;
```

> ```
> 000000_0
> ```

```
! cat /tmp/t_ext/000000_0
;
```

> ```
> 1<--->Hello<--->world
> 2<--->Good<--->Bye
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This works as long as your tables contain only "primitive" types (no structs, arrays, maps etc.).
I really pushed the envelope here.

#### Demo

```
create table t (i int, dt date, str string, ts timestamp, bl boolean);

insert into t select 1,current_date,'Hello world',current_timestamp,true;

select * from t;

+-----+------------+-------------+-------------------------+------+
| t.i |    t.dt    |    t.str    |          t.ts           | t.bl |
+-----+------------+-------------+-------------------------+------+
|   1 | 2017-03-14 | Hello world | 2017-03-14 14:37:28.889 | true |
+-----+------------+-------------+-------------------------+------+
```

---

```
select  regexp_replace
        (   
            printf(concat('%s',repeat('$$%s',field(unhex(1),*,unhex(1))-2)),*)
           ,'(\\$\\$)|[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]'
           ,'$1'
        )
        
from    t
;
```

> 1$$2017-03-14$$Hello world$$2017-03-14 143728.889$$true

Comment: Check updated answer. I have simplified the solution assuming `$$` does not appear anywhere in your data